# Rails: Query for has many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have following associations

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :post
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
end
```

For a user I get all the posts,

```
@posts = current_user.posts
```

I need all the categories associated with @posts. So I need something like this

```
@categories = @posts.categories
```

So how can I get the associated categories of posts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use     **includes** to load categories of each post

```
current_user.posts.includes(:categories)
```